# npm install selenium-webdriver econnrefused

Tags: node.js, selenium

I am trying to install selenium webdriver using npm, but I got error below several time for these two days. 
I am not behind any proxy, I have internet access, no firewalls. 
It seems that some servers does not response...

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'selenium-webdriver' ]
2 info using npm@3.6.0
3 info using node@v5.7.0
4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 silly fetchPackageMetaData selenium-webdriver
8 silly fetchNamedPackageData selenium-webdriver
9 silly mapToRegistry name selenium-webdriver
10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
11 silly mapToRegistry registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
12 silly mapToRegistry uri http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
13 verbose request uri http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
14 verbose request no auth needed
15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 3:16:20 PM
16 verbose request id 05294dd339569a9b
17 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
18 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.31.17.162:80
19 info attempt registry request try #2 at 3:16:31 PM
20 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 185.31.17.162:80
22 info attempt registry request try #3 at 3:17:32 PM
23 http request GET http://registry.npmjs.org/selenium-webdriver
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.43.162:80
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for selenium-webdriver { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.43.162:80]
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   syscall: 'connect',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   address: '23.235.43.162',
24 silly fetchPackageMetaData   port: 80 }
25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
29 silly install printInstalled
30 verbose stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.43.162:80
30 verbose stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
30 verbose stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
30 verbose stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
31 verbose cwd C:\Program Files\nodejs
32 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
33 error argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "selenium-webdriver"
34 error node v5.7.0
35 error npm  v3.6.0
36 error code ECONNREFUSED
37 error errno ECONNREFUSED
38 error syscall connect
39 error Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.43.162:80
39 error     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
39 error     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
39 error     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1057:14)
39 error  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 23.235.43.162:80]
39 error   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
39 error   syscall: 'connect',
39 error   address: '23.235.43.162',
39 error   port: 80 }
40 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
40 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
41 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: are you behind a proxy?

Comment: yes, my mistake, I thought that there is no proxy... just use this suggestion http://jjasonclark.com/how-to-setup-node-behind-web-proxy/ and error is resolved

Comment: i created an answer @drasko982 so we can close this one out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're behind a proxy.  Just like the error says,

```
40 error If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
40 error 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

be sure to run `npm help config` and resolve your issue